# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^{x} \sin^{2}(3t)dt$

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^{x} \sin^{2}(3t)dt$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^{x} \sin^{2}(3t)dt=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x} \sin^{2}(3t)dt}{{x^3}}$$

I know that the limit of $\frac{1}{x^3}=0$ and that $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\sin^{2}(3t)dt$ is continuous because $\sin^{2}(3t)$ is continuous$\rightarrow$ integrable $\rightarrow F$ is continuous. Can I be sure that $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)=0$ without finding the antiderivative?

Comment: Note that $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 1/x^3$ is not defined. Only sided-limits are and equal $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Yes you can, and then you can use L'hopital's rule.

Comment: Note that $F$ is *differentiable*, which is much more than continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can be sure that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} F(x) = 0$ because the integrand is bounded. In particular, $|F(x)| \le |x|$. Or given that you know $F$ is continuous, $F(0) = 0$ is enough.

No, you cannot say that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1 {x^3} = 0$, because it's wrong.

No, it's not necessary to compute the antiderivative. To first order, $\sin^2 3t \approx 9t^2$, so

$$F(x) \approx 3x^3$$

and the limit is $3$. The error here is $O(t^3)$ in the integrand, so $O(x^4)$ after integrating. This doesn't affect the limit.

Comment: Why does the fact that $F$ Is continuous promises that its value at $x=0$ is $0$?

Comment: It doesn't. The fact that $F(0) = 0$ **and** that $F$ is continuous together imply that $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x) = F(0) = 0$. The fact that $F(0) = 0$ is a basic property of integrals.

Comment: Sorry if it is stupid to ask but why $F(0)=0$, this is what I do not get (Becuse it is an $integral \int_{x}^{x}$?)

Comment: What is the area above the point $0$ below the curve? Draw a picture if you don't believe it is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Apply L'Hôpital and use the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\displaystyle\int_0^x \sin^2 3t \, dt}{x^3}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin^2 3x}{3x^2}=
\lim_{x\to 0}3\,\Bigl(\frac {\sin 3x }{3x}\Bigr)^2 = 3
$$

Comment: I'd suggest ordering the last limit as $$\lim_{x \to 0} 3 \left(\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}\right)^2$$ instead. It's more easily identifiable as the form $\sin t / t$.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to compute the definite integral as a function of $x$.  Then divide by $x^3$.  Then take the limit.

Comment: This is certainly a way to do it...yet it is not *a necessary* one. But the integrals  $\;\int\cos^2t\,dt\;,\;\;\int\sin^2t\,dt\;$ are pretty standard so this is not a bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could expand $\sin^2(3t)$ as a Taylor's series. Integrating is easier now, since it is essentially a polynomial. You then divide the resulting polynomial by $x^3$ and take the limit.

It's a bit more troublesome, but more fun.